# Why doesn't this statement throw a StackOverflowError?

Tags: java, stack-overflow

I just saw this *weird* piece of code in another question. I thought it would result in a `StackOverflowError` being thrown, but it doesn't...

```
public class Node {
    private Object one;
    private Object two;
    public static Node NIL = new Node(Node.NIL, Node.NIL);

    public Node(Object one, Object two) {
        this.one = one;
        this.two = two;
    }
}
```

I thought it was going to thow an exception, because of the `Node.NIL` referencing itself to build.

I can't figure it out why it does not.

Comment: probably because of `static` but i am not sure

Comment: What I would expect is that the `NIL` field is constructed as it it was declared as `new Node(null, null)`, because when the constructor is called, `Node.NIL` hasn't been set to anything yet.

Comment: @khelwood yep, based on answer i understood the same think.

Comment: Please never use this in production code. It can provide a nice trivia, but I would consider this to be deliberate obfuscation.

Comment: @chi i won't for sure, but i saw this piece of code on another question, and i was confused about how it could work.

Comment: Not sure why you thought this would explode. How would the stack trace look like?

Comment: I thought because `Node.NIL` was given to the constructor of `Node.NIL`, but Eran's answer made it clear.

Answer (score 100, accepted):

`NIL` is a static variable. It is initialized one time, when the class is initialized. When it is initialized, a single `Node` instance is created. The creation of that `Node` doesn't trigger creation of any other `Node` instances, so there is not infinite chain of calls. Passing `Node.NIL` to the constructor call has the same effect as passing `null`, since `Node.NIL` is not yet initialized when the constructor is called. Therefore `public static Node NIL = new Node(Node.NIL, Node.NIL);` is the same as `public static Node NIL = new Node(null, null);`.

If, on the other hand, `NIL` was an instance variable (and wasn't passed as an argument to the `Node` constructor, since the compiler would have prevented you from passing it to the constructor in that case), it would be initialized every time an instance of `Node` was created, which would create a new `Node` instance, whose creation would initialize another `NIL` instance variable, leading to infinite chain of constructor calls that would end in `StackOverflowError`.

Comment: Thanks, you made it clearer, the way it works is still odd to me. But at least i understand why it works this way.

Comment: If `NIL` was an instance variable, it would not compile with the error `Cannot reference a field before it is defined`.

Comment: @FlorianGenser Good point. I wrote this part before noticing that `Node.NIL` was passed to the constructor.

Comment: java.awt.Color is actually a good demonstration of static variables in action. It has a bunch of different colors, like Color.BLUE, which also contains references to all the other colors... This dazzled me back when I first started in Java.

Comment: Thanks for that @sfdcfox i'll take a look on this.

Answer (score 28):

The **variable** NIL is first given the value `null` and then initialised once top to bottom.  It isn't a **function** and isn't defined recursively.  Any static field you use before it is initialised has the default value and your code is the same as

```
public static Node {
    public static Node NIL;

    static {
        NIL = new Node(null /*Node.NIL*/, null /*Node.NIL*/);
    }

    public Node(Object one, Object two) {
        // Assign values to fields
    }
}
```

This is no different to writing

```
NIL = null; // set implicitly
NIL = new Node(NIL, NIL);
```

If you defined a **function** or **method** like this, you would get a StackoverflowException

```
Node NIL(Node a, Node b) {
    return NIL(NIL(a, b), NIL(a, b));
}
```

Answer (score 20):

The key to understand why it doesn't cause infinite inititialization is that when the class `Node` is being initialized, the JVM keeps track of it and *avoids* re-initialization during a recursive reference to the class within its original initialization. This is detailed in [this section of the language spec](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/specs/jls/se8/html/jls-12.html#jls-12.4.2):

> Because the Java programming language is multithreaded, initialization of a class or interface requires careful synchronization, since some other thread may be trying to initialize the same class or interface at the same time. **There is also the possibility that initialization of a class or interface may be requested recursively as part of the initialization of that class or interface**; for example, a variable initializer in class A might invoke a method of an unrelated class B, which might in turn invoke a method of class A. The implementation of the Java Virtual Machine is responsible for taking care of synchronization and recursive initialization by using the following procedure.

So while the static initializer is creating the static instance `NIL`, the reference to `Node.NIL` as part of the constructor call does not re-execute the static initializer again. Instead it just references whatever value the reference `NIL` has at that time, which is `null` in this case.